# How to calculate a sports team cohesion by how often a team plays together

Tags: correlation

I’m not sure where to start with this so here goes:

I’m researching cohesion within a team environment.

Using soccer as an example. There are 20 teams in a league.

Each team has a squad of 30 players but each game they only play 11 players.

I am after a measure/ ranking of which teams play a more consistent lineup of 11 together (with the hypothesis that when players play together more, they are more cohesive).

Eg an older team that has played multiple seasons together with the same lineup.

I could sum the games played individually but not sure if there is a more “correct” way of doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

For player $i$, calculate the number of games they have played to be $n_i$. This might be not an integer depending on substitutions / injuries etc.

Rank the $n_i$ for a given team and then calculate $C(k)$ to be how many of the $n_i$ you need to add up in order to sum to at least $kN$, where $N$ is the number of games that the team has played and $k$ is some parameter.

If you choose $k=11$ you'll get the total number of players who have been used in the season. Choosing, say, $k=9$ will give you a lower number.

The more cohesive the team the lower the value of $C(k)$. You could experiment with $k$ to see what was most useful.

Comment: I like this alot. And I could potentially use a 3-4 season window for a more extended measure. Thanks alot!

Comment: now to figure our how to write the `python` function to calculate

Comment: Let us know how you get on.